# Change value of cells before it's rendered into datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

I have a web app I'm trying to write that will get the percentages of supplies left in a printer. and display that in a friendly 1-100 percent number. to get that number i must multiply what is left by 100 then divide that by the total possible.

I have not been able to take the data that is coming from a sql server table and modify it before it is rendered into the data gridview. Any help would be appreciated.

I've already tried in the code behind to convert it to integer with no luck. Here is my code.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" OnRowDataBound = "changeToPercent" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="p_ipaddress" HeaderText="p_ipaddress" 
                SortExpression="p_ipaddress" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="s_prtmarkerssuppliesdescription" 
                HeaderText="s_prtmarkerssuppliesdescription" 
                SortExpression="s_prtmarkerssuppliesdescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="s_prtMarkersSuppliesLevel" 
                HeaderText="s_prtMarkersSuppliesLevel" 
                SortExpression="s_prtMarkersSuppliesLevel" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XrxDBCWWConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="usp_SUPPLYPERCENTAGE" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="percentBox" DefaultValue="10" 
                Name="PCT_REQUESTED" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="PRINTER_ID" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have no CS Code to use because everything i have tried has failed miserably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the premature post. I had given up entirely editing my code so instead i went to the source and looked at the stored procedure to see if i could make it work there. Just so happens that you can do Mathmatical function INSIDE your SELECT statement.

This is what i added in the select.

```
SELECT ((s_prtMarkersSuppliesLevel *100) / s.s_prtMarkersSuppliesMaxCapacity) as s_prtMarkersSuppliesLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wiring up the GridView's RowDataBound event, where you would have access to the Row data, and can update them before it gets bound to the grid view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

```
void GridView2_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  // Display the company name in italics.
  e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

}

}
```

Comment: That would work however i guess i should have stated earlier if i haven't that i'm trying to do mathmatical functions on the values. so i have to convert it to an INT then do a percent calculation but i can't seem to convert it.

Comment: I guess you can make the column a TemplateField instead of using a BoundColumn, and do the conversion and calculation in the ItemTemplate. `<asp:templatefield headertext="Author Name">
            <itemtemplate>
              <asp:label id="FirstNameLabel"
                Text= '<%# Eval("au_fname") %>'
                runat="server"/> 
              <asp:label id="LastNameLabel"
                Text= '<%# Eval("au_lname") %>'
                runat="server"/>
            </itemtemplate>
          </asp:templatefield>`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but i managed to edit my sql store procedure to do that mathematics